# NGINX 502 - Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, jsp, jboss, sslhandshakeexception, bad-gateway

**My Client is hosted on NGINX and JBoss is used as the server. I'm facing this NGINX 502 bad gateway. Help me resolve this, please. I've attached my error log for NGINX.**

2023/06/02 16:02:20 [info] 1516730#1516730: *581375 client 10.80.20.1 closed keepalive connection
2023/06/02 16:03:11 [error] 1516731#1516731: *581476 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.80.20.1, server: erptest.globusone.com, request: "GET /GmSSOLogin.jsp HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.80.20.15:8443/GmSSOLogin.jsp", host: "erptest.globusone.com", referrer: "https://erptest.globusone.com/"

2023/06/02 16:03:18 [error] 1516731#1516731: *581476 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.80.20.1, server: erptest.globusone.com, request: "GET /GmLLogin.jsp HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.80.20.15:8443/GmLLogin.jsp", host: "erptest.globusone.com"

2023/06/02 16:03:52 [error] 1516731#1516731: *581476 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.80.20.1, server: erptest.globusone.com, request: "POST /GmGlobusOnePortal.jsp HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.80.20.15:8443/GmGlobusOnePortal.jsp", host: "erptest.globusone.com", referrer: "https://globusmedical.oktapreview.com/"

2023/06/02 16:05:14 [info] 1516731#1516731: *581504 client 10.80.20.1 closed keepalive connection
2023/06/02 16:07:38 [error] 1516730#1516730: *581531 connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.80.20.1, server: erptest.globusone.com, request: "GET /GmEnterprisePortal.jsp HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.80.20.15:8443/GmEnterprisePortal.jsp", host: "erptest.globusone.com"

Whenever I try to hit the URL, I'm facing this exception, read through some documents regarding SSL handshake error but unable to find proper solutions.